# Compute $(1+i\sqrt{3})^{23}$.

Tags: trigonometry

Compute $(1+i\sqrt{3})^{23}$.

Binomial theorem can be used, but seems trigonometric approach will be better and not unwieldy.

Need find angle in radians, that has $\cos(\theta)= 1, \sin(\theta)= \sqrt{3}$$\implies \tan(\theta)=\sqrt{3}\implies \theta = \pi/3$

But, have a doubt : $\cos(\pi/3)= 1/2$, not $1$, similarly $\sin(\pi/3)= \sqrt{3}/2$, not $
\sqrt{3}$.

So, cannot state like one below:

---

$e^{i \pi/3} = \cos(\pi/3) + i \sin(\pi/3)$

Hence, $e^{i 23 \pi/3 } = \cos(23\pi /3) + i \sin(23 \pi/3)$

---

All can add is that can find different multiples of $\pi/3$ that fit . Say, $\tan(\pi/3), \tan(4\pi/3),\tan(n\pi + \pi/3)
$.

But, it is impossible to find suitable integer $n$, if $\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{3}$, as $0\le \cos(\theta), \sin(\theta) \le 1$.

Comment: Since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $(1+i\sqrt{3})^{23} = \left( 2\left(   \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}   \right)\right)^{23} = 2^{23}e^{i\frac{23\pi}{3}}$

Comment: @MattE. Then get: $2^{23}.(\cos (23\pi/3)$$+i\sin(23\pi/3)$. As $\pi/3\times 6= \pi$, so get: $= 2^{23}.(\cos (-\pi/3)+i\sin(-\pi/3))$$= 2^{23}.(1/2+i(-\sqrt{3}/2))\, ?$

Comment: Yes, you are calculating this correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Let $z=1+i\sqrt 3$. First you have to find the module $|z|$. Then find such $\theta$ that $z/|z|=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. This'll give you $z=|z|\cdot(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Hope you mean $|z|= 2, z/2=(\cos(\pi/3) +i\sin(\pi/3))$. If correct, then request geometrical interpretation of binomial expansion :$2^{23}\times (1/2+i.\sqrt{-3}/2)$. I mean, the point $1/2, \sqrt{-3}/2)$ will lie on second (lower) intersection of two circles with unit radius and centres $(0,0), (0,-1)$.

Comment: @jiten yes. You previously forgot to take |z| into account. Now you can calculate the power of z.